# Discord.py `discord.Guild.roles` returns `property object at 0x10d57a720` or `'property' not iterable`

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

> discord.py = Version | 1.6.0:latest
>
> Python = Version | 3.9

I have been banging my head all day on this one.

For some reason in discord.py version 1.6.0 `discord.Guild.roles` doesn't return a list it is stated [here in the docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=discord%20guild%20roles#discord.Guild.roles). But a property object that is not iterable.

I have tried unpacking like it was a tuple a for loop, etc, etc and even tried to get around this by using `fetch_roles()`, but that too is not iterable. I'm just at a dead end on this one.

My goal is to iterate this list and find "Basic". A role I have in my Guild. Then add it to a new user using a `@client.event` decorator to check for `on_member_join`. All of it works for sending a message to that user, but I cannot get the roles to return a list of roles.

Any help is appreciated.

```
async def on_member_join(member):
    try:
        server = member.guild.name
        user = member.id

        roles_list = discord.Guild.roles
        # Gets the member role as a `role` object

        # should iter over list of roles from above
        role = discord.utils.get(roles_list, name="Basic")

        # Gives the role to the user
        await member.add_roles(role)

        ...
```

Comment: There's no such version of discord.py, the latest is `1.6.0`, I think you're confusing it with your pip version...

Comment: Ah, ok no you are definitely I looked at the wrong version.

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed to refer to the class itself, but to the instance.

```py
roles_list = server.roles # You defined it above, or `member.guild.roles`
```

Comment: Doesn't this just get me the member's roles? I had this setup this way before and I only get an empty list. `[]` which would run through the `discord.utils.get()` as `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'`

Comment: @EdwinCarra No, that's ``member.roles``, ``member.guild.roles`` first takes the member's guild, and then all the roles in that guild.

Comment: It will give you the guild's roles, not the members', as stijndcl said, to get the members' roles you can use `member.roles`

Comment: Sadly I'm getting Nonetype object has no attribute I'd when I run this through the utils.get.